# Scalar subquery produced more than one element. Need to get better code for filling null values

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to SQL, I am trying to use the averge of latitude information for each station to fill the null values of the corresponding start station. I keep getting the error "Scalar subquery produced more than one element."

```sql
SELECT *, 
CASE
WHEN start_lat IS NULL THEN start_lat = (SELECT AVG(start_lat)  FROM `capstone-project-353309.data_2021.data_2021`GROUP BY start_station_name)
ELSE start_lat = start_lat
END,
CASE
WHEN start_lng IS NULL THEN start_lng = (SELECT AVG(start_lng)  FROM `capstone-project-353309.data_2021.data_2021` GROUP BY start_station_name)
ELSE start_lng = start_lng
END,
CASE 
WHEN end_lat IS NULL THEN end_lat = (SELECT AVG(end_lat) FROM `capstone-project-353309.data_2021.data_2021` GROUP BY start_station_name)
ELSE end_lat = end_lat
END,
CASE 
WHEN end_lng IS NULL THEN end_lng = (SELECT AVG(end_lng) FROM `capstone-project-353309.data_2021.data_2021`GROUP BY start_station_name)
ELSE end_lng = end_lng
END,
FROM `capstone-project-353309.data_2021.data_2021`
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to compute with this query?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use the averge of latitude information for each station to fill the null values of the corresponding start station

I think you're trying to do following query:

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng),
       IFNULL(start_lat, AVG(start_lat) OVER w) AS start_lat,
       IFNULL(start_lng, AVG(start_lng) OVER w) AS start_lng,
       IFNULL(end_lat, AVG(end_lat) OVER w) AS end_lat,
       IFNULL(end_lng, AVG(end_lng) OVER w) AS end_lng
  FROM `capstone-project-353309.data_2021.data_2021`
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY start_station_name);
```

Comment: Hi @Jaytiger, the dataset I am working on has station names and their latitude and longitude for different rides that were booked for a bike rental dataset. Example: 
ride_id  start_station_name  start_lat  start_lng  end_station_name  end_lat  end_lng

Some of the end station and start station names are missing for some rows. I want to fill the names of these end and start stations using other rows which have same start/end latitude and longitude. I am finding it very hard to do it in SQL as I am new to it. Do you have any suggestions. I am working with BigQuery.

Comment: btw thanks a lot for help, I tried running your code in BgQuery but it didnt run.....sorry I am a noob.

Comment: @AdityaRathore, I've fixed it. try it again.  And for filling missing station names, if you post it in another question with sample data, I'll look at it in my free time.